# How to get timezone offset in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

In javascript, I want to get my local timezone offset such as `-04:00` as a string. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `d1 = new Date();    
d1.toString();    
// "Tue Jul 07 2020 00:24:46 GMT+0200" `


this solve your problem?

Comment: not exactly, I am looking to get the string value in this format exactly `-04:00`.

Comment: that returns a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Rather then do your own division to get the hours, just use the functionality already in the date object:

```
    const date = new Date();
    const tzOffsetNumber = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    const tzDate = new Date(0,0,0,0,Math.abs(tzOffsetNumber));
    console.log(`${ tzOffsetNumber > 0 ? '-' : '+'}${tzDate.getHours()}:${("" + tzDate.getMinutes()).padStart(2,'0')}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date object for this task.

```
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

Now you got a string like -120 you can format as you like. You can divide by 60 to get hours and then use + or push:

```
offset = (offset / 60) + ":00";
```

one line:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60 + ":00";
```

Edit: Since you seem having problems, i made you a code example you can test.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

if (offset >= 0 && offset < 10) {
  offset = "0" + offset;
} else if (offset > -10) {
  offset = "-0" + offset.toString().substr(1);
} else {
  offset = "00";
}
offset += ":00";

alert(offset);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not handling 00:XX in case those exists.

Comment: for me, it gives me "4" when it should be "-4".

Comment: You're doing something wrong aside from my example. At least in my case is printing -2:00. Be carefull with implicit type cohertion while doing comparations or operations in general. Use ===, !==, <==, >==.

Comment: If `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` is negative, timezone is positive, and vice versa.  It says how many minutes should be added to the local time to get GMT/UTC.  New York is  "-05:00" and `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` there will return `300` minutes == 5 hours.  Israel is "+02:00" and `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` there will return `-180` == -3 hours.  New York is behind GMT and Israel is ahead of GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
const date = new Date()    
const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset()
const sign = offset >= 0 ? '-' : '+'
const hours = Math.abs(offset / 60)
const minutes = Math.abs(offset % 60)
const hoursStr = `0${hours}`.slice(0, 2)
const minutesStr = `0${minutes}`.slice(0, 2)
console.log(`${sign}${hoursStr}:${minutesStr}`)
```

Note that not all timezones end at hours. Some countries use half hour timezones, like +03:30.

Comment: what's with all the `const`s?
I got `-0` for minutes...

Comment: @iAmOren Good catch on -0. Both hours and minutes needed to be absolute values. I'm not sure if I follow your question about consts. Do you mean why use `const`, instead of `let` or `var`? Or why declaring all those variables?

Comment: When I copy-paste code to check into dev tools, I cannot edit it if it contains `const`s.  
Sometimes I forget to get rid of them, so I have to open a new dev tools tab.  
`let` is better in that respect.  I will never use either: "To `var` or not to `var` - is the only question (for me)" and the answer: Always and only `var`.  My logic: JavaScript is a loose language - why `const`rict it?!? :) :) :)  Someone wants a type of  `var` to never change? - C++!  Found a work-around: wrap code in `{``}` - but then I cannot get `var`iable's values...

Answer (score 0):

I'd created a function...

```
function timezone(date=new Date()) {
  var timezoneOffset=date.getTimezoneOffset();
  var sign=(timezoneOffset<0)?"+":"-";
  var minutes=Math.abs(timezoneOffset);
  var hours=Math.floor(minutes/60);
  minutes=minutes-60*hours;
  return sign+("0"+hours).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+minutes).slice(-2);
}
```

You can pass a `Date` object, if you don't, one will be created.
`timezoneOffset` is in integer minutes: East of GMT = negative, West = positive.
`sign` is the opposite of the offset.
`minutes` `abs` = we've already got the sign, let's deal with absolute value.
`hours` - whole number of multiples of 60 minutes.
`minutes` - reminder of what it was minus 60 times whole hours.  Could be done with `%`, it's a matter of preference.
`return` -

- sign is a string: "+" or "-"
- ("0"+hours) is now a string: 7 becomes "07", 11 becomes "011", that's why:
- .slice(-2) return the last 2 characters: "07" returns just that, "011" returns "11".
- same for minutes.
- and a ":" between.

You can test on different `timezoneOffset` values manually by replacing `date.getTimezoneOffset()` with a number.

Comment: Well?  Good answer?  If so - please select and up-vote it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
function getTimeZoneOffset() {
    var t = new Date().toString().match(/[-\+]\d{4}/)[0];
    return t.substring(0,3) + ":" + t.substr(3);
}
```